# Microstrategy Table Selection

Tags: microstrategy

I have a problem.
I have made 2 fact tables, which are almost identical - they only have 1 attribute and 1 metric in report.

Now, there are 3 Attribute Qualification Prompt in the report 1 required 2 optional.
Table A has all 4 attribute mapped(3 Attribute Qualification Prompt) whereas Table B has 3 (only 2 Attribute Qualification Prompt) mapped.
Requirement is when User selects the 3rd prompt mapped only to Table A it should go to Table A whereas if that 3rd Prompt is not selected then MSTR should go to Table B.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Currently it is not clear what are you trying to do and what goes wrong. For example - what is `MSTR`?

Comment: I assume from your question that when the user doesn't use the third prompt, the report SQL contains only columns from table B. If this is the case the SQL Engine should use automatically Table A, if this is not the case, you can play with the logical size of Table B, increasing it.

Comment: Hi , Based on prompt Selection Table selected by MSTR should change.

Comment: If 3rd Prompt is selected it should go to Table A as the 3rd prompt Attribute is mapped to table A and has Logical Size 47 where Table where 3rd Prompt is not mapped to has Logical Size of 37 so when the 3rd prompt is unanswered it should go to Table B which is not happening.Please help

Comment: I know that this is something I've done with conditional SQL Queries. Maybe this is something best done with two separate queries that are conditional on the count of prompts. Basically, IIF Count of [Used Prompts] > 2 then run Query 1(joining to requisite table 1), else run Query2 (joining to requisite table 2) // Caveat - I'm just learning about Microstrategy, but my SQL knowledge is quite deep.